# Rails - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, connection, uri

I want to send a POST/GET from a Rails application to a specific address. However, when I run the application, I got the error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)" Below are my codes:

```
  def show
    @uri = URI('example.com/getuser?user=bob&email=bob84@gmail.com')
    @profile = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    puts @profile
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure the server you're trying to query is up and running?

Comment: yes it is. Tried pasting the url in the interner browser and it works.

Comment: Try this : `@uri = URI('http://example.com/getuser?user=bob&email=bob84@gmail.com')`

Comment: okay i just realised its a dumb mistake.. haha putting the 'http://' in front definitely works! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm marking this as a reply in order to make it more readable for people who might come here in the future. This was first replied in the comments.

The problem was that `URI` isn't HTTP-centric. So the protocol needs to be specified.

The following works :

```
 @uri = URI('http://example.com/getuser?user=bob&email=bob84@gmail.com')
```